# Token de inicio de sesión no coincide con token en cualquier controller

Tags: laravel

Verán, estoy almacenando un log de sesión en base de datos, al recuperar en mi listener el token generado al iniciar la sesión con

```
     $session->cod_session = \Request::session()->get('_token');
```

Me arroja un valor X, hasta allí bien; se guarda en la tabla de logs.
El problema es que cuando ejecuto la misma consulta en cualquier controller, el valor es distinto ¿Por qué sucede ésto?

Comment: ¿podrías explicar más la parte de "cuando ejecuto la misma consulta en cualquier controller, el valor es distinto ¿Por qué sucede ésto?", por favor :)

Comment: Por supuesto.  Con ésto me refiero a que si en un controlador o vista escribo **Session::token()**  el valor que obtengo es totalmente distinto.

Comment: Mm ¿puedes checar si las cookies se están escribiendo bien en filesystem?, para checar esto podrías postear los valores que contiene tu archivo `config/session.php`

Comment: return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,   'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,    'same_site' => null,
];